# Loading Fonts from Jar while writing PDF-A (archive) file

Tags: java, fonts, itext, itextpdf

I am using PdfAWriter to create PDF-A (PDF Archive format) file and using .ttf to embed fonts in PDF. My TTF files are under config folder .
And when I try to create font like below it works in local

```html
Font BOLD_10 = FontFactory.getFont("./config/FreeSansBold.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 10);

Document document; //Document created using PDF-A writer

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 50,50 });
table.setWidthPercentage(new Float(100));

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Header 1", BOLD_10);
document.add(paragraph);
```

If I try to build a jar file and place the .tff inside the jar, below code doesnt work, since it wont be able to find the path of ttf file:

Font BOLD_10 = FontFactory.getFont("./config/FreeSansBold.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 10);

How can I configure my font file path to pick dynamically from jar?

We have tried using built-in fonts and BaseFont instead of .ttf, but they don't work (throw exception at run time) for "PDF-A" file.

Apart from using TTF, is there any alternative to embed fonts in a PDF-A file?

Comment: Solved the problem like this -

(1) Placed the .ttf files under "com/mycompany/pdfutility/fonts" directory and included them in the jar file.

(2) Referred to this file in the code like this:
Font BOLD_10 = FontFactory.getFont("/com/mycompany/pdfutility/fonts/FreeSansBold.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 10);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem like this - 
(1) Placed the .ttf files under "com/mycompany/pdfutility/fonts" directory and included them in the jar file. 
(2) Referred to this file in the code like this:

Font BOLD_10 = FontFactory.getFont("/com/mycompany/pdfutility/fonts/FreeSansBold.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 10);

Comment: Thanks to http://compgroups.net/comp.text.pdf/itext-basefont-loading-from-classpath/261207

Comment: Could you take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/52736441/3169868

Answer (score 1):

If you use iText 7, you can try this:

First put your `font.ttf` file in resources dir such as `fonts/simsun.ttf`

Then,

```
    byte[] fontByte = IOUtils.toByteArray(Main.class.getResource("/fonts/simsun.ttf").openStream());
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontByte, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
```

IOUtils is from [commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/project-summary.html)